# 360 video not working on jwplayer

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jwplayer, 360-virtual-reality

I'm using jwplayer plugin for PHP, it works fine for normal video. but it doesn’t display like in youtube with 360 video format where you can click to view different angles, it just display as normal video.

is there any control i need to set for jwplayer to display 360 video and drag to view different angles ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the JW Player VR Plugin in the player setup:

```
plugins: {
        'https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/plugins/vr/vr.js': {}
    }
```

[Demo and example code here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/innovation/360-video/). Note, this requires a JW Player Premium account or higher.

Comment: Thanks Josie, I'll look on your given example

Answer (score 0):

Also need to set the primary player. Because 360 vr does support the html5 player.

"primary" : "html5"